# If $p$ divides $(q-1)(q+1)$, why does $ p=q+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p,q$ be primes such that $p >q$. If   $ p | (q-1)(q+1)$, why does $p=q+1$?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $p$ cannot divide $q-1$, so it must divide $q+1$. But $p\geq q+1$. So $p=q+1$. This result is true irrespective of whether $q$ is prime or not.

Comment: I don't understand why $p$ must divide $q+1$. Is this only because they're both primes?

Comment: If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then either $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: Hence $p=3, q=2$.